# The "spaces.messages.create" API only allows 120 calls per minute but Document says 3000 call per minute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I've given Google Chat permission to send messages on my behalf as a user, and I'm using "**spaces.messages.create**" an API to allow users to send messages, I have tested 3000 calls of this API to send messages to space 120 only succeed and 2880 ERROR 429(To Many Request). Although the documentation said that 3000 API calls can be made each minute, only 120 are really permitted per minute. Is there anything I have missed in the given document https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/limits

I need this API "**spaces.messages.create**" call to send message via google. 3000 call per minute

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a 429, you should implement [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff#Binary_exponential_backoff_/_truncated_exponential_backoff). There are times that a service must scale, handle backlog, process errors, manage maintenance, etc. By delaying and retrying you will achieve a better/higher send rate and have fewer failure conditions.